# Regex to extract last two octets of IP address (3rd and 4th Octet) in Google Sheets

Tags: regex

I need help to extract **last two octets of IP address (3rd and 4th Octet)** by using regular expresssion.

This regex works to **extract first two octet (1st and 2nd Octet)**:

(1?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])

You can try it [here https://rubular.com/r/ynDa71Zd1M2f24](https://rubular.com/r/ynDa71Zd1M2f24)

But I dont know how to extract 3rd and 4th octet. 
Anybody can help me with?

- Input : 192.168.1.1 Output : 192.168.0.0/16
- Input : 192.168.2.1 Output : 192.168.0.0/16
- Input : 10.10.1.1 Output : 10.10.0.0/16

Thank you,

Comment: Do you want to match an [ip number](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html)?

Comment: I think you should just match every octet individually and grab the groups for 3 and 4

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird, what I need to do is to implement it in google sheet like below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qarF8O9WNUCfopYTqZJyOvO6m0RPwN8WGd4VsMO7p-c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Faro You could use a pattern like https://regex101.com/r/zYZb1f/1 Then use capturing group 1 followed by `0.0/16` in the replacement.

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use for example a pattern to match an ip like format and use a capturing group for the first 2 parts including the dot.

In the replacement use the capturing group value `$1` followed by `0.0/16`

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$","$10.0/16")
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c7LYwR/1)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird! This solution works. Really appreciate this :)

Comment: This does not capture the last 2 octets, this captures an entire address.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle Please read the question, and then the answer before you start downvoting. And no, it does not capture the entire address. It captures the first 2 parts in group 1, and it matches the rest to be replaced with `0.0/16`

Comment: The question asks how to extract the last two. This captures the entire address. I guarantee you it does.

Answer (score -1):

### Solution

You can use something like this:

```
(?P<first>\d{2,3})\.(?P<second>\d{1,3})\.(?P<third>\d{1,3})\.(?P<fourth>\d{1,3})
```

Or if you don't have named capture group support just use:

```
(\d{2,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})
```

This will split your strings into four different groups, each containing one octet of the ip.

### Example

```py
import re

pattern = r"(?P<first>\d{2,3})\.(?P<second>\d{1,3})\.(?P<third>\d{1,3})\.(?P<fourth>\d{1,3})\n?"
matcher = re.compile(pattern)

ips = """
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
"""

result = matcher.findall(ips) # [('192', '168', '1', '1'), ('192', '168', '1', '2')]
```

Comment: Where have you seen they want a Python solution?

Comment: @Toto It doesn't really matter, I provided the pure regex and they can use it however they prefer.
I did provide a python example to make sure it's clear, but they can easily convert it to any other language.

Comment: `\d{,3}` works only in Python, in other regex flavour, it match a digit followed literally by `{,3}`, see: https://regex101.com/r/SmCJlg/1

Comment: Moreover it's better to split on dot then check each value that must be between 0 and 255

Comment: @Toto "better" is a relative term. The OP asked for a regex solution, so I provided one, if he wanted to just get the octets another way I would have suggest it. About the `\d{,3}`, you are correct, I edited my answer to include the needed `1` (`\d{1,3}`)

Comment: Hi @OryanMoshe I tried your solution but it didn't work
https://rubular.com/r/84X2dF8IL0zp2P

I try to implement it in google sheet, it didn't work too.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qarF8O9WNUCfopYTqZJyOvO6m0RPwN8WGd4VsMO7p-c/edit?usp=sharing

Or maybe, there is something I missed in implementing it?

Comment: This does not capture the last 2 octets, this captures an entire address.